# to convert KLs, what are the absolute continuity requirements?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, information-theory

$
\def\KL#1#2{\operatorname{D_{KL}}(#1 \| #2)}
\def\E{\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}}
\def\dee{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}}
$

I'm trying to convince myself that the following identity holds:

$$\KL{P}{R} = \KL{P}{Q} + \E_{x\sim P}\left[\log\frac{q(x)}{r(x)} \right]
$$

where $P,Q,R$ are probability measures on $\mathbb R$, and $q,r$ are the densities of $Q,R$, respectively. Derivation below.

This identity seems to hold **if $P\ll Q$ and $P\ll R$** (with notation '$\ll$' meaning 'absolutely continuous with respect to').  My questions are: is it true that this requirement is sufficient? Is this requirement necessary?

---

##### Derivation:

To be explicit here, densities $p,q,r$ are the the RN derivatives of $P,Q,R$ respectively, each with respect some common measure $\nu$, which we could take to be the Lebesgue measure or counting measure.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\KL{P}{R} 
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{r(x)} \dee{\nu(x)}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\log\frac{p(x)q(x)}{q(x)r(x)} \dee{\nu(x)}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \dee{\nu(x)} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\log\frac{q(x)}{r(x)} \dee{\nu(x)} \\
&= \KL{P}{Q} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\log\frac{q(x)}{r(x)} \dee{\nu(x)}
\end{aligned}
$$

In order for this derivation to work, I think I need to assume

- $P\ll R$ (definition of KL, in the first line)
- $P\ll Q$ (so that $p(x)/q(x)$ is defined in the second line)

Is this correct, or am I missing something? Do I need to make any other assumption? In particular does this requires that $Q\ll R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\KL#1#2{\operatorname{D_{KL}}(#1 \| #2)}
\def\E{\operatorname*{\mathbb{E}}}
\def\dee{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}}
$

You are correct: in order for the KL-divergences $\KL{P}{R}$ and $\KL{P}{Q}$ to be well-defined, you must have that both $R$ and $Q$ are each absolutely continuous with respect to $P$.

Given that, your identity follows. You do not need any other assumptions.

Note you can also write your identity in more general case (where densities $p,q$ need not necessarily exist):

$$
\KL{P}{R} 
= \KL{P}{Q} 
+ \E_{P}\log\frac{\dee Q}{\dee R}
$$

where $\frac{\dee Q}{\dee R}$ is the Radon-Nikodým derivative of Q wrt R.

Now, think about it like this: the absolute continuity requirements $P\ll Q$ and $P\ll R$ mean that for any $P$-measurable set $A$,

- $Q(A)=0\implies P(A)=0$
- $R(A)=0\implies P(A)=0$

So anything in the support $P$ is guaranteed to be in the support of *both* $Q$ and of $R$.

If I understand the root of your question, you're worried about whether it's "safe" to evaluate the expectation term ($\E_{P}\log\frac{\dee Q}{\dee R}$). You can be comfortable, it's safe! Maybe you will see this if you just note that $\E_P\left[f \right] = \int f dP$, and for any measurable function $f$, all you need is that it be well-defined over the support of $P$.  You don't need to worry about whether $f$ is defined outside the support of $P$, because you don't ever evaluate it there in computing this integral.  In this case, $f$ is $\log\frac{\dee Q}{\dee R}$, which is defined on the support of $P$ as argued above.